# Routing in progressive web app

Tags: javascript, html, routes, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make route work in my progressive web app. The root page right now is **index.html**. I have next page called **admin.html**. The problem I am having here is making url look like `https://sampleapp.com` route to root page i.e **index.html** and `https://sampleapp.com/admin` route to **admin.html**.

I have tried looking into tutorials but could not find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on what you are using for your server.

In nginx you can configure your tires to try finding the file with the path name and if that files try finding the file name with '.html' on the end and the same for apache, but you'd change the .htaccess file.

Comment: Please give more details of technologies being used.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is taken care of by the server. If a request comes in, to http://sampleapp.com/ for example, it is up to the server to decide what to return. All webservers, like [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) or [Node.js/Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) have mechanisms to make sure you get *admin.html* when making a specific request.

The *Service Worker* doesn't mind routing. In case of caching it just stores the result of a request to the server and enable the situation where it can return the same result without going to the server again. From there you can extend the functionality of you service worker with more advanced caching strategies.

Just keep in mind that with a Progressive Web App you extend your existing 'normal' website. From a website point of view nothing changes. The Service Worker and the Manifest.json file make it a PWA and make it behave better using the right browser.

Answer (score 0):

depend your framework and server. incase you use Service Worker for caching you cab use path of your app instead path of file